# Не работают ссылки на R.raw и R.drawable находящиеся в Базе данных

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не работают ссылки в БД на имеющиеся картинки и аудио файлы в папках `Raw` и `Drawable`. К примеру у меня в БД реализовано так:

`|     Sounds   |     Pictures        |`

`| R.raw.sound1 | R.drawable.picture1 |`

Получаю я данные из БД так:

```
int mSounds = cursor.getInt(0);
int mPictures = cursor.getInt(1);
```

И теперь когда я пытаюсь задать например картинку:

```
imageView.setBackground(mPictures);
```

Приложение падает, и выдает ошибку что `mPictures` пуст.

Comment: Ничего хорошего из этого не выйдет. значения в R генерируются, в любой момент времени вы можете получить рассинхрон базы и значений в R. Ну в принципе уже получили.

Comment: Предложите рабочую альтернативу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете в БД задать стринги с названием ресурсов, а затем вынимать их индентификаторы примерно так:

```
String imageName = "picture1"
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", "package.name");
imageView.setImageResource(resID);
```

Comment: Поправочка. `ImageView` в `setBackground` принимает `Drawable`, а для установки картинки из ресурсов нужен `setImageResource`

Comment: спасибо, исправил

Comment: Для одиночного метода хорошо, но с массивом проблема. У меня идет запрос один к многим, и в некоторых позициях массив строк

Comment: Но в целом, да, это ответ на мой вопрос.